# Python's xml.etree.ElementTree equivalent to C++ XML library

Tags: c++, python, xml, dom, elementtree

I found [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) library very versatile and handy XML processor. How about C++? I found some C++ XML tools (Xerces-C++, TinyXml), but it's more like a [xml.dom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [cpp-elementtree](https://github.com/dw/cpp-elementtree/). It's fairly well tested at this point and is designed to mimic exactly the effortless API you're used to.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [iksemel](http://code.google.com/p/iksemel/) , its written in C but its fast and robust.